# Are there cases where the extremum ( or local extremum) of a function can be found algebraically ( without calculus)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, maxima-minima, elementary-functions

Suppose I know that the function $f(x)=x²$ has a minimum value on $\mathbb R$.

Could I determine this munimum value algebraically ( without using calculus).

If I set $x² \geq m$, I only get this :

$x² \geq m$

$\iff \sqrt{x²} \geq \sqrt{m}$

$\iff |x| \geq \sqrt{m}$

$\iff (x \geq \sqrt{m}) \lor (-x \geq \sqrt{m}) $

$\iff (x \geq \sqrt{m}) \lor (x \leq\ -\sqrt{m} ) $

Does this tell me that $m=0$ , which is the minimum value of $x^2$ on $\mathbb R$?

Is there a way to determine algebraically the minimum value of some functions, at least on a given interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the function $x^2$ the answer is very simple: by the rule of signs
$$ x\neq 0\Rightarrow x^2>0,\qquad x=0\Rightarrow x^2=0$$
hence:

i) $0$ it the minimum value attained  by the function $x^2$;

ii) $x=0$ is the only minimizer.

Of course there are many other similar cases (e.g. $x^{2n}$)